# After installing the Linux ubuntu, my windows desktop doesn't change at all?

Tags: system-installation

after installing the Linux Ubuntu, my windows desktop and the system doesn't change at all and it is still the same as usual. 
Can anyone tell me how to be the same as the one shown on website?
Did I have anything wrong during the installation?

Comment: What website? It could be that you installed a different flavor or that that website is not using Unity/Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

You have to boot into Ubuntu. Ubuntu won't change your windows installation.

Comment: Downvoter, would you care to explain why you downvoted?

Comment: Some possible reasons are [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8070/what-are-the-reasons-to-downvote-answers) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/213575). Take into account that the vote sometimes is subjective.

Comment: Ah, now I see - didn't take the edit into account - first he only said his desktop didn't change